# For what values does the series converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Consider the sequence $$ x_n=\frac{1}{n^{b}}\left(\frac{1}{n^{a}}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{c}}.$$ where $a,c>0,b\in \mathbb{R}.$

I think the series $\sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ converges for $b>1,a>0,c>0$ as
$ x_n=\frac{1}{n^{b}}\left(\frac{1}{n^{a}}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{c}} \sim\frac{1}{n^{b}}\left(\frac{1}{cn^{a}}+1\right) \sim \frac{1}{n^b}$
and diverges for $b\leq 1$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Correct, but these are not the only values for $a,b,c$ for which the series converge. Are you looking for all such values ?

Comment: For b>1 case, c<0 with (a>0  and a<0) also possible ,,,,with the Abel's th.

Comment: and also a=0 with c>0 and c<0 together with b>1 possible

Comment: There are also,,,many more possibility

Comment: And also for any a and any c(not equal to 0), you have to adjust that b should be greater than a/c +1